# filter df using key words

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a df:

```
item_name   price   stock
red apple    2       2
green apple  4       1
green grape  4       3
yellow apple 1       2
purple grape 4       1
```

I have another df:

```
Key Word   Min_stock
red;grape   2
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
item_name   price   stock
red apple    2       2
green grape  4       3
```

I would like to filter the first df based on the second df, for keyword, I would like to select item_name that contains either key word in Key Word cloumn.

Is there any way to acheive it?

Comment: Can there be multiple keywords in df2? or just one value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` the DataFrames, you can compute a regex from the [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ted and [`explod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)ed `df2`, then [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the min values and filter with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = (df2.assign(kw=df2['Key Word'].str.split(';'))
        .explode('kw')
        .set_index('kw')['Min_stock']
     )
# red       2
# grape     2
# blue     10
# apple    10

regex = '|'.join(s.index)
# 'red|grape|blue|apple'

mask = df1['item_name'].str.extract(f'({regex})', expand=False).map(s)
# 0     2
# 1    10
# 2     2
# 3    10
# 4     2

out = df1[mask.notna()&df1['stock'].ge(mask)]
```

output:

```
     item_name  price  stock
0    red apple      2      2
2  green grape      4      3
```

*NB*. for generalization, I used a different `df2` as input:

```
Key Word   Min_stock
red;grape   2
blue;apple  10
```

Comment: Why it returns ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). when I try to run mask = df1['item_name'].str.extract(f'({regex})', expand=False).map(s)

Comment: With the provided input?